# socket.io dont update when i use chat rooms

Tags: node.js, sockets, vue.js, websocket, socket.io

I have tried for 2 hours to get it working with NO success.
const stock = io.of('/stocks');
stock.on('connection', socket => {

When i do that my messages is not updating on the client side..

But when i do this: io.on('connection', socket => { 
then it works. But i need to have different chat rooms. And i have no idea why the io.of not works.

I have tried with everything that has come to my head. I dont understand why it just works when i dont use the io.of, it is really weird.

What can i do for it to work correctly?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

custom namespace in socket.io, you have to decare it first, then connect.

```
const nsp = io.of('/my-namespace');
nsp.on('connection', function(socket){
                       console.log('someone connected');
                                                        });
nsp.emit('hi', 'everyone!');
```